# nested listed to dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
[[0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
 [0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0]]
```

and I'd like to convert it to a dictionary looking like this:

```
{1:[0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
 2:[0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0]}
```

I have tried to do this in a list comprehension but I can't seem to find the right answer. It doesn't work out since I'd like to start the 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict comprehension` instead of list comprehension, using `range(len(a)`:

```
output = {i+1:a[i] for i in range(len(a))}
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
 2: [0,36,112,123,25,117,55,26,17,113,121,118,107,114,104,64,0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [
    [0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
    [0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0],
]

result = {index: sub_list for index, sub_list in enumerate(lst, start=1)}


print(result)
```

Output:

```
{
    1: [0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
    2: [0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0],
}
```

Comment: You can do `enumerate(lst, start=1)` and change `index + 1` to `index`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import count

lists = ...

print(dict(zip(count(1), lists)))
```

Comment: While this code may help with the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it:

```
lis=[[0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0],
     [0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0]]
dicti={}
for i in range(1,len(lis)+1):
    dicti[i]=lis[i-1]
print(dicti)
```

I have created an empty `**dictionary**`. Then, I have iterated through the `list` and appended the `values` of the `dictionary` assigning integers to the `keys`.

Notice how i have used `range(1, len(lis)+1)`, so that `i` has the first value as `1`.

Then we can add the `key:value` pairs to the `dictionary` using the `for loop`.

This gives the desired output:

```
{1: [0, 100, 47, 105, 120, 4, 46, 115, 103, 131, 14, 74, 8, 122, 91, 0], 2: [0, 36, 112, 123, 25, 117, 55, 26, 17, 113, 121, 118, 107, 114, 104, 64, 0]}
```

Hope this was helpful!